# How do I run spell check on an Rmarkdown document in Emacs + ESS?

Tags: r, emacs, r-markdown, spell-checking, ess

Emacs with ESS makes a great IDE for `R`, even better with `polymode-R` and `polymode-markdown`.

When working with Rmarkdown (`*.Rmd`)files I haven't been able to find an easy way to spellcheck the text components.

How can I spellcheck just the running text in an Rmd document?

Comment: I don't use a running spell checker, but have you tried `flyspell`? (This question may be closed as it is [off-topi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *recommend or find a book, tool, software library*.)

Comment: spell check is `F7` in Rstudio (but it'll report lots of false-alarms in code chunks)

Comment: Rstudio is great, but looking for an Emacs + ESS answer

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the regions to be ignored by `ispell`. For `.Rmd` files

```` (add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("^```" . "```$")) ````

should do the trick. You can then spell check the buffer with `ispell-buffer` and it will skip your code blocks.

Comment: May I ask where this is documented? I could not find it in the Emacs manual.